# ASP drop down box to list information from 2 SQL Server columns

Tags: html, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I've got a drop down list of customers. However, some of those customers get listed 2 or 3 times because they have multiple cities. What I would like to do is include the city in the same drop down list next to the city so that each entry is unique

```
<%
Dim DataConn
Dim custsel
Dim SQL

Set DataConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set custsel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
DataConn.Open "DSN=***;UID=***;PWD=***;"

SQL = "select custname, city FROM log.dbo.Customers order by CustName"
custsel.Open SQL, DataConn
%>

<table align="center" border="0">
    <tr><th colspan="2"><b>Test Billing Transaction Summary</b></th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr color="#ff7f26"></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="50%" align="right">Customer Selection: </td>
        <td width="50%" align="left">
            <select name="custsel" id="custsel">
                    <% if Request.Form("custsel") = "All" then %>
                <option value="All" selected>All</option>
                    <% else %>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                    <% end if %>
                    <%While Not custsel.EOF%>
                <option value="<%= custsel("custname") %>"><%= custsel("custname") %></option>
<%
custsel.MoveNext
Wend

custsel.Close
Set custsel = Nothing
DataConn.Close
Set DataConn = Nothing
%>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="right">Summary Type: </td>
        <td align="left"><select name="datetype" id="datetype">
                <option value="">Date Type:</option>
                <option value="LTD">Last Trade Day</option>
                <option value="MtD">Month to Date</option>
                <option value="YtD">Year to Date</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="right">Start Date: <input value="" type="text" name="datepickstart" id="datepickstart" required></input></td>
        <td align="left">End Date: <input value="" type="text" name="datepickend" id="datepickend" required></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Execute" id="billingsubmit"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr color="#ff7f26">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you know exactly what you want/have to do. What is the question?

Comment: I'd like to have the list populate the Customer Name as well as the City they belong to. Some Customers are in multiple cities. So currently my list will show "Customer 1, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 3, ETC". Instead I'd like it to show " Customer 1 - City0, Customer 2 - City0, Customer 2 - City1, Customer 2 - City2, Customer 3 - City0, ETC".  I was hoping to combine them somehow but I'm not sure of the correct way. All the ways I have tried have failed so far.   <option value="<%= custsel("custname") %>" + "<%= custsel("city") %>"

Comment: .... omg. I found a solution. Thank you, it was under my nose this whole time... UGH frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the final line in my select box to:

```
<option value="<% =custsel("custname") %>" + "<% =custsel("city") %>"><% =custsel("custname") %> :<% =custsel("city") %></option>
```

However, I'd like to be able to call on the "CustName" and the "City" independently on the next page.

I'm currently calling the custname with:

```
<% dim custselect custselect = request.form("custsel") %>
```

Can I call on the city with:

```
<% dim cityselect cityselect = request.form("custsel") %>
```