# retrieving two variables from select box

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a select box that is filled with 2 variables.

```
    <select name="custsel" id="custsel">
            <% if Request.Form("custsel") = "All" then %>
        <option value="All" selected>All</option>
            <% else %>
        <option value="All">All</option>
            <% end if %>
            <%While Not custsel.EOF%>
        <option value="<%= custsel("custname") %>+<%= custsel("city") %>"><%= custsel("custname") %> :<%= custsel("city") %></option>
    </select>
```

However when I check the request.form information on the next page I only receive the first variable. So if I swap

```
<%= custsel("custname") %>+<%= custsel("city") %>">
```

to be

```
<%= custsel("city") %>+<%= custsel("custname") %>">
```

I'll get the city name to show up in the next page's request.form info.

I've tried passing the variables with hidden inputs but I can still only get the first one to show up. To do this I added

```
onchange="document.form1.hiddeninput1.value=this.value"
```

Is there an easier way to pass both of these variables?

Comment: Why do you [keep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404010/using-variables-from-previous-asp-page) [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398308/asp-using-variables-from-previous-page-in-sql-query) [this same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383027/asp-creating-variable-for-sql-query) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379361/asp-drop-down-box-to-list-information-from-2-sql-server-columns)?

Comment: 1. Use `&` to concatenate strings, not `+`. 2. Use a delimiter between the name and city. 3. On the receiving page, use `Split` with that delimiter to get the two parts. You've received this answer in multiple places, you just need to actually *do* it. JavaScript is absolutely not needed for any of this.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martha. I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong which is why I keep asking the same question in multiple ways. I have `:` between the name and city as seen in the example above. When I try to split on the next page `custselect = split(request.form("custsel"),":")` I am able to call `<%=custselect(0)%>` but when I try to include `<%=custselect(1)%>` I get an "Internal Server Error 500"... Is my delimiter in the correct location? I'm still trying to learn as much as possible but I'm not in any type of formal classes/training.

Comment: There's no delimiter of any sort in `<%= custsel("custname") %>+<%= custsel("city") %>`. Change that to `<%=custsel("custname") & ":" & custsel("city")%>`, and *then* try `cust = Split(Request.Form("custsel"),":")`.

Comment: Yep. That did it. Now I'm off to learn how to write different responses based on the user selection. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Note that my above comment is exactly what I [posted as an answer to one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38400762/121333). (Well, except for using IDs instead of names, but the principle doesn't change.)